# Asteroid Catalog

Tags: asteroid, rotation, asteroid-belt

Where can one find asteroids or comets that contain water ice suitable for a human mission. Perhaps there is comprehensive catalog of **small bodies** that can be searched for characteristics such as:

mass: 
size: 
rotation period: 
rotation axis: 
composition: 
albedo: 
orbit: 
location: 
distance to Earth: 
surface characteristics:

Comment: The Minor Planet Center maintains [catalogs](http://www.minorplanetcenter.net/data) of the orbits, but not the other parameters you mention. Most of those parameters are unknown for most minor planets.  You can use the JPL [HORIZONS](https://ssd.jpl.nasa.gov/horizons.cgi) system to calculate relative position and distance to Earth at whatever time you like.

Comment: If there is no help here in maybe a week or so, you might consider asking in [Astronomy stackexchange](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/) instead. Just fyi here are two other questions related to ice in space; [What forms of water ice have been observed and verified in the solar system?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/18374/12102), and also [If there is actual ice on the moon, why hasn't it sublimated?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/21381/12102)